# Displaying Time_zone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I added a time_zone_select field to my User signup form and added a column (:tz) to my User table.

```
     <td>Select Timezone</td><td><%= f.time_zone_select :tz %></td>
```

However, it is not saving to the database with any value... i.e. if I call

```
     <%= current_user.tz %> nothing is displayed.
```

Any ideas on this one? Probably a simple solution like assigning values to the time zones, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some more of the surrounding code (like your form_for statement).  Also, what data type is tz? What does the controller method look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have added `:tz` to your `attr_accessible` method at the top of whatever model you added the `tz` column too.